Language of jummah Khutbahs
Assalamualikum warahmatullahi wabarakatuh
Q1: Why do we find some people doing jummah Khutbahs in ARABIC ENGLISH MIX can we find anywhere from the prophet doing it or requesting it to his companion any action of any of the three best generations or anyone before the fall of Othman empire?
Q2: Is Arabic not Islamic language and moving away is striping people away from it ?

Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. To learn more about our site and model consider taking the [tour] and checking our [help]. You have asked two questions in one post, please avoid it see for example in our meta.

Further as for your first questions the reasons for that are very subjective and your second question rather looks like a rhetorical question. See also already asked questions Should the khateeb deliver the Friday khutbah in Arabic? and Was Khutbah delivered in the Arabic language in non-Arabic speaking lands during the 4 caliphs rule?

There are several reasons for this.  Moreover, it is not against Islam as it is done in practice.   Because, first of all, the imam briefly fulfills the conditions of the Khutbah in accordance with the Sunnah.  This is advice, salawat and prayer.  They do the rest according to worldly conditions.  First of all, one of the reasons for this and most importantly, in European countries, for example, the state requires that Khutbah be read in the local language.  The imam has to comply with this.  Another reason is that the congregation or those present will benefit from it in the best possible way.  For example, let's say you live in Germany.  Especially children and young people become more familiar with the local language both at school and on the street, so they may not be able to understand Arabic or their native language sufficiently.  An additional repeated Khutbah in the local language will both facilitate the understanding of these young people and comply with the laws of the relevant country.   For example, the situation is more complicated for Turks living in Europe.  The imam first fulfills the requirements of the Khutbah in Arabic, reads the salawat and prayer, and stands up again and reads the Khutbah published for that week by the Turkish State Presidency of Religious Affairs, both in Turkish and then in the language of the country he is in, and ends his Khutbah with salawat and advice.

You would likely best be served by asking them. Perhaps they are lazy, perhaps forgetful, perhaps it is a habit of which they are unaware or attempting to break.
While Arabic is the language of revelation and of the prophet (pbuh), mastery of Arabic is a long journey, and we should not be critical of anyone with a pure heart who makes steps forward (however slow) on that journey.
